# Соединение двух виртуальных адаптеров на примере VPN приложений. [C#]

Tags: c#, сеть, wcf, vpn

VPN приложения (для примера возьмём hamachi, tungle, evolve) создают локальный адаптер, с помощью которого эмулируют локальную сеть.

1. Как происходит эта эмуляция? Почему компьютер начинает воспринимать удалённый виртуальный адаптер как локальную машину?
2. Как сделать нечто похожее в C#

   - С уже имеющимся виртуальным адаптером (rout-ы не настроены никакие, только только произошла установка драйвера).
   - Условия возьмём "лабораторные": соединяем 2-3 машины с белыми IP адресами. (машины находятся за роутерами).

### **UPDATE по реализации**

WireShark-ом посмотрел какие пакеты приходят на виртуальный адаптер.

В основном это SSDP и IPv6 трафик (*скрины приложу... может быть*).

SSDP и IPv6, скорее всего, дело конечностей PNRP протокола.
PNRP используется при создании P2P соединения.

Теоретическое подтверждение того, что P2P может быть использован для эмуляции локальной сети:

1. Открываем консоль и вводим `netsh p2p pnrp peer add registration 0.NAME`
2. Не закрывая 1 консоль открываем вторую и пишем `netsh p2p pnrp peer resolve 0.NAME`
3. Во второй консоли высветятся все IP адреса, ассоциирующиеся с данным пиринговым именем.

[image: Первая консоль]

[image: Вторая консоль]

Теперь, для начала, нужно установить p2p соединение по PNRP протоколу между компьютерами из одной подсети (подключённых к 1 роутеру).

Искал как реализовать P2P связь в C#. Нашёл библиотеки **System.Net.PeerToPeer**
 **System.Net.PeerToPeer.Collaboration**
И программный фреймворк:
**Windows Communication Foundation** (**WCF**).
*Изучал его по книге Основы WCF (2008 г.). Не против чего поновей*

Пробовал через библиотеки. Всё что получилось, так это программно зарегистрировать peer. (*то, что делали в консоли*)
(*возможно, с помощью PeerToPeer.collaboration-а можно сделать что-то ещё но мне лень/я тупой*).

WCF в этом плане интересней. Спустя несколько попыток, кажется, сумел соединить 2 компьютера привязкой-Франкенштейном из  и  (стандартная **NetPeerTcpBinding** не подошла. Я не знаю как ею соединить 2 компьютера даже если они из одной подсети).
ПК1 - ip **10.17.17.17**
ПК2 - ip **10.17.17.16**

Но ответа на ping запросы всё равно нет (*в Evolve-е есть*). Позже кину ссылку на Github, туда закину драйвер виртуального адаптера и то, что я сделал в WCF.

Есть подозрения, что ошибка в контракте (1) (*одностороннее общение, а ping основан, насколько я знаю, на TCP. Исправлю*).

В Итоге второй пункт вопроса можно разбить на 2 похожих вопроса.

1. Как создать приватное глобальное PNRP облако средствами C#.
2. Как с помощью WCF создать P2P подключение, похожее на то, что создают перечисленные в самом начале VPN приложения ( *я сам не понимаю что написано во этом пункте* ).

Полезные ссылки:
 [Чат сделанный с помощью WCF и custom resolver-а](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17321/A-simple-peer-to-peer-chat-application-using-WCF-n)
- сразу скажу, то что нам нужно не делает, но является хорошим примером. Думаю попробовать внедрить в этот код Франкенштейн привязку (*проверю наличие ошибки в контракте (1)*).

Comment: Первая часть вопроса довольно простая. Реальный адаптер имеет некое физическое соединение с остальной сетью (провод, радио-канал) и использует это соединение для приема/передачи пакетов. Для виртуального адаптера канал VPN-туннеля выполняет функции физического соединения. Сервер VPN - выполняет роль обычного свича, соединяя всех подключенных к нему клиентов так же, как обычный свич или WiFi-точка соединяют своих клиентов подключенных физически (с оговоркой, что VPN-свич смотрит сразу в виртуальную и физическую сети сервера). Реализацию делать не пробовал, так что тут не подскажу.

Comment: подсеть должна быть с маской /252